# Reference of returned object?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

If I have a class as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
   List<String> list{get;set;} 
...
}
```

And then execute:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
instance.add('string') ;
```

Will that new entry in the list be added to the member variable instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you trying to do should be more like

```
 class MyClass{
    public List<String> list{get;set;} 
 }
```

and then execute

```
 MyClass instance = new MyClass();
 instance.list.add('string');
```